# Getting compile time error in audioplayers dart package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am new in flutter and I followed londonappbrewery course, in that course she teach us to use audioplayers packages so I follow her and import it on pubspec.yaml but when I want to run my flutter app it give this error. Please give solutions I am running it on physical device with Android 10. [This is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J11HG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think it might solved by changing the following line in the `build.gradle` from:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

To

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
```

…or whatever the latest version of Kotlin available is. Make sure to update your Kotlin version on Android Studio as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following and please make sure that you have an Android project setup with Kotlin,

This file ensures that the Android project is using Kotlin `android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/your_app/MainActivity.kt`

In `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10' // Update this version or add this line
  ...
  dependencies {
       ...

       // Make sure this line is here
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

In `android/app/build.gradle` make sure this line is there too at the bottom,

```
dependencies {
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` use updated gradle version `gradle-6.5-bin.zip` for **distributionUrl**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

If any confusion or question please leave a comment.